# How to debug for loop after skipping some loop of it

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

How can I debug a loop! I have a loop of 50000 count and want to debug the end of it. I have to press F8 for it 50000 time to get the end result. How can I do by skipping the 49900 loop and directly go to last loop by debugging!
Thanks

```
 for (int i=0;i<50000;i++)
    // some code;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a conditional breakpoint.

First, put a breakpoint at the line where you want to debug. After that, right-click on that breakpoint, so the following window will appear:
[image]

Now you can specify at which point you want to trigger this breakpoint, in your case, it would be:
[image]

Now you can run your app with the debugger attached.

More info here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html

Comment: Thanks. This is the correct solution! It worked. But I do not know why the loop run slow after doing this!

Comment: @SWIK If you think that this is the correct solution, you should accept (and upvote) it. The loop is slower because of the debugger.

Comment: Yes. I accept it but I could not find accept option here. I think reputation is not enough

Comment: No reputation is needed to accpet an answer. To accept - you should press the grey 'V' near the answer's score. To upvote - use the grey up arrow.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use if block with break point into loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
    if (i == 49900)
        Log.d("1","1"); // break point here

    // do stuff
}
```